# R spplot label overlapping

Tags: r, label

The data I'm working on has lots of same value for each level(daily rainfall in southeast 5 states), eg:

```
values(r1) <- c(rep(0.1,25575),rep(0.2,25575),rep(0.3,25575),rep(0.3,25575))
```

therefore in the output image, the map is full of same label/value for each level, is there a way that each level only has label showed for only once or twice, eg: label 0.1 showed only once for level 1, not 25575 times?

Here is a test code:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
setwd("C:/Users/rosaR/Data/PRISM")

r1 <- raster(xmn=-88.77083, xmx=-75.02083, ymn=24.0625,ymx=36.97917, nrow=310, ncol=330,crs='+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0') 
#values(r1) <- c(rep(0.1,25575),rep(0.2,25575),rep(0.3,25575),rep(0.4,25575))   
values(r1) <- c(rep(seq(from=0.1,to=3,by=0.1),3410))
newproj <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
r1 <- projectRaster(r1, crs=newproj)

png(file=paste("test.png",sep=""), width=1350, height=700, units="px")
at=c(0,0.15,0.3,0.45,0.5,0.65,0.7,0.85,0.9,1.05,1.1,1.25,1.3,1.45,1.5,1.65,1.7,1.85,1.9,2.05,2.1,2.25,2.3,2.45,2.5,2.65,2.7,2.85,2.9,3)

spplot(r1,
#sp.layout=list(
#list('sp.polygons', spTransform(SE_sea1, CRS(newproj)),fill="white", first=F, col=NA), 
#list('sp.polygons', spTransform(SE1, CRS(newproj)), alpha=1, lwd=2, first=F)),
xlim=c(613190.6,2173441),ylim=c(121319.4,1774699),col.regions=rainbow(29),colorkey=F,at=at+.Machine$double.eps,contour=T,labels=list(labels=format(at)),col=grey.colors(1),maxpixels=102300)    
dev.off()
```

If I set the breaks at=c(0,0.15,0.25,0.35,0.5), the map would look perfect, but since my original dataset was huge and inevitably there are values same as the level value, maybe not as much as 25575, but 20-100 times, which I would like to reduce to less than 5 times showing in the image.

I tried to add: 1) method="flattest"; 2) list('sp.pointLabel', r1, label, col='grey'); 3)list("sp.text", coordinates(raster_data), raster_data); but none seemed to work for my RasterLayer,

any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your example is not reproducible (because we don't have access to any of the shapefiles). Could you create a reproducible example, perhaps with some example data that comes with one of the packages? (e.g. we all have access to the `iris` data, though that is not a shapefile).

Comment: Sorry about the shape file, they don't really matter in this case, so I've edited them off...

Comment: Could you do `at=c(...) + .Machine$double.eps`? or is that too specific to this example?

Comment: The label looks much better, thanks, but the polygon of red is also gone, and I need that...

Comment: Just lower your first cutoff, e.g. prepend an `at=c(0, ..)`.

Comment: The only problem left now is the label showing on the map becomes "0.100000e+02" instead of "0.1", is there a way to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `.Machine$double.eps` to your `at` values so that the cutoffs just miss the at values. Then, you can use the `labels` argument to adjust what labels get shown (so you get "0.1" rather than "0.100000e+02")

The `labels` argument to `spplot` is passed to `levelplot` (`?sp` says `...` are passed to `levelplot` (grids, polygons) or `xyplot` (points), but `raster` is a "grid"-type). Reading `?levelplot` says to look at `?panel.levelplot` for more details on the `labels` argument. Finally, `?panel.levelplot` says that `labels` can be a list with element "labels" describing the labels to put on the contours.

So the result is your code except:

- adjust the `at` to add `.Machine$double.eps` (a small number)
- adjust the `label` to give the labels as "nice" numbers.

Giving:

```
at <- c(0, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45)
spplot(r1, xlim=c(613190.6,2173441), ylim=c(121319.4,1774699), 
       col.regions=rainbow(4), colorkey=F, contour=T,
       # add a small number to the colour cutoffs to prevent ties
       at=at + .Machine$double.eps,
       # change the labels to be "pretty". See `?format`
       labels=list(labels=format(at)),
       col=grey.colors(1), maxpixels=102300)
```

[image]

(colours look pretty awful but I figure you can fix it from here :P)

Comment: As I applied to my real data set, unfortunately I have 30 breaks/at, I have made some change to the code accordingly now, and as u mentioned the code does work for small amount of breaks like 5, but now the map went crzay again...